# symfony 1.4 How can i include Id or auto generated primary key field in slug

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, slug

I need to form slug from fields **id** and name.
like id-name

**Schema Code**
Sluggable:
  fields: [***id***, title]

But i am unable to so.

Where as when i try some other column like
Sluggable:
  fields: [**unique_id**, title]
It works :(
Can anybody help???

Thanx

Comment: But that should work, what's your schema YML for the table?

Comment: @jamie  IvService:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name: { type: string(500), notnull: false }
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    Sluggable:
      fields: [name]
I think id is auto generated thats the cause of the issue. Any solutions though??

Answer (score 0):

You can override the setSlug() method in the model class

Answer (score 0):

I added this trick in the form saving action:

```
$title  = $object->getTitle();
$object->setTitle($title." ");
$object->save();
$object->setTitle($title);
$object->save();
```

This workaround save twice the object and the second one takes the ID.
The problem is that in the first save(), it doesn't know the ID of the record.